# Having with SMTP error in rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, smtp, ruby-on-rails-2

I am having the following error in rails while using the normal smtp:

> Net::SMTPFatalError (554 Message rejected: Email address is not verified. The following identities failed the check in region US-EAST: 
>   ):

Is their a way in rails 2 to bypass all smtp errors so that the application does not halt with a blank page?

Answer (score 1):

Inside app/config/production.rb file:

```
# Disable delivery errors, bad email addresses will be ignored

config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
```